# openssl no-ec2m configure option

Tags: openssl

Several years ago we ported openssl 1.0.2l to Vxworks OS.
I have been asked to add to openssl elliptic curves for signing/verification purposes.
In the configuration of openssl I see the following defined option: no-ec2m
Question: Do I need this option for signing/verification? What is it ?

Comment: The answer for "no-ec2m" option:  a)  https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776125/are-the-openssl-gfp-functions-slow-drop-in-replacements-for-the-gf2m-functions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.